# Jar command is not working as expected

Tags: shell, jar, zip, war

I am trying to update a .war file by updating a xml file with following command.

```
jar -uvf web-4.3-SNAPSHOT.war WEB-INF/web.xml
```

and the output is

> WEB-INF/web.xml : no such file or directory

and does not add the file, but when i execute

```
jar -uvf web-4.3-SNAPSHOT.war web.xml
```

it works and add .xml file to .war.

My .war file has the WEB-INF directory

```
 155 Wed Apr 15 19:52:32 EDT 2015 images/bg-menu.gif
 21653 Wed Apr 15 19:52:30 EDT 2015 WEB-INF/valid.xml
  1151 Wed Apr 15 19:52:30 EDT 2015 WEB-INF/deco.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to update the file within `.war` hierarchy like that.

But you can do it like this.

1. Create a `WEB-INF` directory and add your new `web.xml` file into it
2. Update the war file like this `jar -vfu web-4.3-SNAPSHOT.war WEB-INF/`

Note that you don't specify explicitely the name of the file to be
updated but only the

**name of the directory**

which contains the xml file.